# Has Trump has set any benchmark for winning the trade war(s)?

Tags: donald-trump, trade

It's well known that Trump [said that](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/03/02/trump-trade-wars-are-good-and-easy-to-win.html):

> 'Trade wars are good, and easy to win'.

But unlike in a conventional war, how do you know when you've won a trade war? And I mean this question to be answered from Trump's perspective, preferably using his own words, but that's if not available, at least the words of his administration.

Comment: It is very likely the answer is "no" - but I'll wait to see if anyone can come up something.

Comment: @JamesK: I'd be surprised if nobody among his economics staff has said anything. There are dozens of articles in the press on how/why the US will win the trade war (with China or EU) or that has won it already. Trouble is most of these have varying (and often unclear) definitions of winning actually means. Some examples: the US stock market is doing better than the Chinese one, so the US is winning already, or the EU has already made concessions etc.

Comment: are there clear goals and measurable results? no, not really, it's politics.

Comment: At the risk of sounding cynical... re-election? :P